# minimizing sum of different least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Can we write the minimization problem: 
 $$\operatorname{min}\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|C_i x-b_i\|_2^2$$ as a least square problem?

Comment: Please tell us what the symbols in that expression refer to.

Comment: What norm are you using? Is $x$ in a Hilbert or pre-Hilbert space?

Comment: Is $C_i$ a scalar, a matrix, ?

Comment: $C_i$ is a matrix, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $C_i$ is a $m_i \times n$ matrix and $b_i$ is a $m_i \times 1$ column vector.

If you let $C = \begin{bmatrix}C_1 \\ C_2 \\ \vdots \\ C_n\end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$, then the problem becomes $\displaystyle\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\|Cx-b\|_2^2$.

This is now a least squares problem.

Comment: This will not work as it requires that $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n\sum{m_i}}$.

Comment: $C$ has dimensions $\sum m_i \times n$ and $x$ has dimensions $n \times 1$. Hence $Cx$ has dimensions $\sum m_i \times 1$, which is also the dimensions of $b$. What is the problem?